# Netbeans 10 - Customize syntax checker - Make exception

Tags: netbeans, syntax-error, customization

I'm using Netbeans for web application projects. There I use smarty with some custom tags. Now the syntax checker of Netbeans throws syntax errors and mark all files with these tags as files with errors.

[image: screen]

Are there options to add my own tag rules to the syntax checker to get a correct result or to ignore these explicit error type?

I'm using Netbeans 10.0.

Thanks a lot, 
Chris

Comment: You might consider adding the appropriate "smarty" tag(s) ("smarty" and/or "smarty3"?) to your question.